# Eloquent where is stacking up

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

my problem is as shown below

```
$data = Model::whereRaw(<condition 1>)
$data1 = $data->whereRaw(<condition 2>)
$data2 = $data->whereRaw(<condition 3>)
```

whenever I print `$data2->toSql()` I will get this

```
select * from table where <condition 1> and <condition 2> and <condition 3>
```

instead of

```
select * from table where <condition 1> and <condition 2>
```

Comment: The method `whereRaw()` returns the class instance (method chaining) so `$data`, `$data1` and `$data2` contains a reference to the same object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because $data, $data1,$data2 pointer to the same object in memory ...

to solve this:

```
$data = Model::whereRaw(<condition 1>);

$data1 =(clone $data)->whereRaw(<condition 2>)

$data2 = (clone $data)->whereRaw(<condition 3>)
```

Comment: You dont need to clone it twice, you can use the original variable for the last condition.

Answer (score -1):

try to

```
$data  = Model::whereRaw(<condition 1>);
$data_cloned = $data->replicate();
$data1 = $data->whereRaw(<condition 2>);
$data2 = $data_cloned->whereRaw(<condition 3>);
return $data1->toSql();
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: This is just a principle of a passing by reference and passing value. Since the model was returning a reference not a value you have to duplicate the reference to avoid overriding of  value. `$data->replicate()` means separating of reference.

Comment: Please add all explanation **to your answer** by editing it